# Regular expression to parse sfv-format files

Tags: python, regex, file, parsing, verification

I'm trying to write a regex to parse an sfv file in python.
Basically, the lines are of the format

> filename crc_bytes

but whitespaces can be added all over the place, including the file name. so the real format is

> (whitespaces)filename(whitespaces)crc_bytes(whitespaces)

when filename can include whitespaces.

Now, I'm trying to extract filename and crc_bytes. So I've tried:

```
'\s*(.+)\s+([^\s]+)'
```

but it parsed

```
'   filename with spaces    crc  '
```

as

```
'filename with spaces   ', 'crc'
```

//too much spaces------------^

Any idea how to get rid of these spaces? probably, look-behind somehow?

#### bonus question:

Comments in sfv files are lines that start with ';'. If anyone would be able to treat comments in the regex I will forever be in his debt.

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you please post an example for a line with a comment?

Comment: sorry... i've rechecked and only lines that start with ; are comments. should i use lookahead?

Comment: If it's the first character, you could simply negate it :`[^;]`

Comment: and, of course, anchor it: ^[^;]. thanks! :)

Comment: hmm.. the ^[^;] swallows the first letter. so lookahead, anyway? :)

Comment: Include it in the parentheses

Comment: but if you put it immediately in the beginning of the regex you would have '(^[^;]\s*.+\S)\s+(\S+)' and will find whitespaces too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Handling filenames with spaces

Using `(.+\S)` forces the filename to end with a non-whitespace (`'\S`) character.

```
>>> import re
>>> reg=re.compile('\s*(.+\S)\s+(\S+)')
>>> reg.findall(line)
[('filename with spaces', 'crc')]
```

### Avoiding comments

You could use lookahead or add negation checks to the regex. I think, however, that adding another regex would be more readable:

```
>>> comment_line_regex=re.compile('\s*;.*')
>>> line1='   filename with spaces    crc  '
>>> line2=';  filename with spaces    crc  '
>>> line3='  ;  filename with spaces    crc  '
>>> lines = [line1, line2, line3]
```

Now we have three lines, two of which are comment line. The following parses only the lines which are not comments:

```
>>> [reg.findall(l) for l in lines if not comment_line_regex.match(l)]
[[('filename with spaces', 'crc')]]
```

Or, in a more verbose fashion:

```
>>> for line in lines:
...     if not comment_line_regex.match(line):
...             print reg.findall(line)
... 
[('filename with spaces', 'crc')]
```

Comment: Probably great! I left the place a few years ago :-)

Comment: well, that means you haven't updated your profile page in a while :)